# Postgres OVER not recognizing sort expression as expected

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have this query to perform a cumulative sum calculation on a table:

```
SELECT *, SUM("Cost") OVER(ORDER BY 1) as "cumulative_sum" 
FROM some_table
```

However, that does not work - the sum is not cumulative, it is the total sum on every row. I have to put the actual name of the column (`id`) in place of `1` in the `OVER` function order for it to work, like so:

```
SELECT *, SUM("Cost") OVER(ORDER BY id) as "cumulative_sum" 
FROM some_table
```

Is there anyway around this? I am working on a project where queries like this will be generated dynamically, and I won't always know the names of the columns.

Comment: `order by` in a window function always requires and identifier. You can't use a column index.

Comment: maybe you can infer the names of the columns from their position before constructing the windowed column? the difficulty here depends on the application emitting the query. A library such as sqlalchemy in python (or similar) may make this task manageable in general.

Comment: This also sounds more like a bug in your library that generates the queries. I am not  aware of any DBMS that would allow column positions in the `order by` of a window function

Comment: however _if there are no partitioning applied and you are always ordering by the first column_ then `SELECT *, SUM("Cost") OVER w as "cumulative_sum" FROM some_table ORDER BY 1 WINDOW w as (ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)`  may work

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I believe postgresql will infer the `order by 1` as `order by <constant>`, so the result will be the same if the OP uses `order by 1` or `order by 'a'` or `order by 100`.

Comment: @HaleemurAli that gives me exactly what I need. Thanks so much!